# how to pen Iphone .plist file in Windows Machine?

Tags: iphone, windows, file-io

In my Iphone application i have .plist file in which i am putting all the Input data. I will further use this data in the code: directly from .plist file.

The problem is that when i am going to open the .plist file in a windows machine, it is not showing its original content. It is just showing the Binary characters or junk characters.

Can any body help me out for how to open the .plist file in the Windows machine, so i can do my data entry in the .plist file in a windows machine also.

Any solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More likely than not, the plist is stored in a binary format for speed and size purposes (XML is bloated and slow to parse).

You'll need to explicitly save your data in a readable format manually or use NSPropertyListSerialization to serialize the property list into XML.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSPropertyListSerialization/dataFromPropertyList:format:errorDescription:

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's to late.
You can use xml editor,but not all of them can work with *.plist files. I use http://www.donkeydevelopment.com

PS

Apple use this document type definition:

< DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">